# Fetching Facebook Cover photo returns JSON without the picture's source

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception, photo

In my app, I am trying to display the Facebook cover photo of my users when others are visiting their profile.

The problem is that sometimes there is an error, but most of the time the JSON response does not contain the source of the cover photo. Is there any permission I need or what could be wrong?

response:

> FB Response:{Response: responseCode: 200, graphObject:
>   {"id":"1159287107464088"}, error: null}

method I use to fetch the cover photo, as in the FB docs:

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext(), new FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onInitialized() {
                accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

                if (accessToken != null) {
                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    params.putString("fields", "cover");
                    new GraphRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            "other_users_fbId",
                            params,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();

                                    if (error != null) {
                                        http.sendIssueToServer("error: " +
                                                error.getErrorMessage());

                                    } else {

                                        try {
                                            Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();

                                            JSONObject cover = obj.getJSONObject("cover");
                                            String src = cover.getString("source");
                                            imageLoader.displayImage(src, coverIv);

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            http.sendIssueToServer("FB Response:" + response.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                    ).executeAsync();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you share your json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any permission, only the App Scoped ID of an authorized User - or just use `/me`. The JSON should look like this (`/me?fields=cover`):

```
{
  "cover": {
    "id": "xxx",
    "offset_y": 0,
    "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/..."
  },
  "id": "xxx"
}
```

If it does not look like this sometimes, make sure the user does have a cover photo or file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thanks, indeed, the problem appeared only when a user did not have a cover photo :)